# Best practice for consent page for authorization code flow with IdentityServer4?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am having a microservice system with backend and frontend hosted on different servers. To authorize and authenticate a user in my frontend app I use '[Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)' flow to obtain an access token (since frontent app is trusted).

Now I want to implement authorization code flow to give permissions to 3rd party apps to act on the user's behalf. To do it, I need the login page and the consent page.

In default examples for IdentityServer4 for this flow, views for login and consent pages are returned by identity server itself (and, maybe, it even use session cookies between login page and consent page).

Since my frontent app is fully trusted, how could I have login and consent screens in this app to reduce duplication?

Maybe, I could make endpoint in identity server to issue the token for the third party app, given that user has access token obtained in trusted frontend app?

Comment: Best practice is to _never trust the client_ and get rid of ROPC. Also maintain single responsibility. In a microservices environment this means that authentication is the task of IdentityServer, not of the client. In fact, the client should be ignorant of user credentials. Please note that by [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) the client isn't the authority to handle the authorization code flow.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I understand this statement when we are talking about third party clients we have no control over. What are the pitfalls in the case I have the same control over identity server as over UI application and they are located in the neighbor repositories?